# Platform where call stack and stack for frames have different locations?

Tags: architecture, hardware, platform

Is there a hardware platforms that natively supports two different memory locations to store the call stack and the stack for stack frames of functions? First — perhaps protected to read and write for user code.
Especially interested in hardware platforms, which are designed for conventional structured languages (i.e. C/C++), but not exotic.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common set-up for really low-resource microcontrollers.

The motivation for this arrangement is usually one or both of the following:

1) There is a limited quantity (often 1 or 2 kB) of on-die SRAM running at core speed, whilst additional memory has slower access times - 1kB is big enough for a few thread-stacks of return address, not for large automatic variables stored on the stack. 
2) Segmented addressing modes in which in-segment memory access instructions encode with shorter op-codes and are therefore fetched quicker from RAM.

This arrangement makes simple cases of function call and return cheap.

In practice, for many CPU architectures - particularly RISC ones - the compiler uses general purpose memory access instructions to create and and consume stack-frames, so the decision as to where the stack frames resides and how they are used is one for the compiler author rather than the CPU architect.

I suspect what you have in mind with this question is protecting return addresses from overwriting by other data in stack frames?

Comment: I think that's a multi-user multitasking environment can be protected from unauthorized access.